# Django 2.2.5 product not displaying in shopping cart

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a e-commerce site using django 2.2.5. I've been following a tutorial on [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/python-ecommerce-build-a-django-ecommerce-web-application/) where the instructor is moving at a rapid pace and he's using an older version of django i am continuously trying to pause just to ensure my code is correctly (it's AWFUL). I am now creating a shopping cart. The price is updating correctly but the product(s) price and description are not displaying. I've back tracked checked all the videos leading up to this part of the project but i can't seem to find what I've done incorrectly, so I've decided to come here for a second / third set of eyes that maybe able to see why the product(s) price and description are not displaying.

cart (cart.html): I have a forloop.counter that is looping through the products and is suppose to display the price and description of products added to the cart.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<div class="pb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 p-5 bg-white rounded shadow-sm mb-5">

          <!-- Shopping cart table -->
          <div class="table-responsive">
               {% if cart.product.exists %}
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                    <div class="p-2 px-3 text-uppercase">Product</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                    <div class="py-2 text-uppercase">Price</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                    <div class="py-2 text-uppercase">Quantity</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                    <div class="py-2 text-uppercase">Remove</div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {% for product in cart.products.all %}
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row" class="border-0">{{ forloop.counter }}
                    <div class="p-2">
                      <img src="{{product.image}}" alt="" width="70" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">
                      <div class="ml-3 d-inline-block align-middle">
                        <h5 class="mb-0"> <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-dark d-inline-block align-middle">{{ product.name }}</a></h5><span class="text-muted font-weight-normal font-italic d-block">Category: Watches</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><strong>{{product.price}}</strong></td>
                  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><strong>3</strong></td>
                  <td class="border-0 align-middle"><a href="#" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
            {% else %}
            <p class="lead">Cart is empty</p>
            {% endif %}
          <!-- End -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row py-5 p-4 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Coupon code</div>
          <div class="p-4">
            <p class="font-italic mb-4">If you have a coupon code, please enter it in the box below</p>
            <div class="input-group mb-4 border rounded-pill p-2">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Apply coupon" aria-describedby="button-addon3" class="form-control border-0">
              <div class="input-group-append border-0">
                <button id="button-addon3" type="button" class="btn btn-dark px-4 rounded-pill"><i class="fa fa-gift mr-2"></i>Apply coupon</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Instructions for seller</div>
          <div class="p-4">
            <p class="font-italic mb-4">If you have some information for the seller you can leave them in the box below</p>
            <textarea name="" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Order summary </div>
          <div class="p-4">
            <p class="font-italic mb-4">Shipping and additional costs are calculated based on values you have entered.</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mb-4">
              <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Order Subtotal </strong><strong>{{ cart.subtotal }}</strong></li>
              <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Shipping and handling</strong><strong>$10.00</strong></li>
              <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Tax</strong><strong>$0.00</strong></li>
              <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Total</strong>
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold">{{ cart.total }}</h5>
              </li>
            </ul><a href="#" class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill py-2 btn-block">Proceed to checkout</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

cart (cart/models.py):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save, m2m_changed

from products.models import Product

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj.user = request.user
                cart_obj.save()
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
            new_obj = True
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
        return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user=None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)


class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = CartManager()


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)


def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
        products = instance.products.all()
        total = 0
        for x in products:
            total += x.price
        if instance.subtotal != total:
            instance.subtotal = total
            instance.save()


m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=Cart.products.through)


def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.subtotal > 0:
        instance.total = instance.subtotal + 6
    else:
        instance.total = 0.00


pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender=Cart)
```

(cart/views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart


def cart_home(request):
    template = "carts/cart.html",
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request, template, {"cart": cart_obj})


def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    if product_id is not None:
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if product_obj in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(product_obj)
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(product_obj)
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

Products View (products/views.py):

```
class ProductDetailSlugView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args,  **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailSlugView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        return context

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        try:
            instance = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Not Found")
        except Product.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            qs = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
            instance = qs.first()
        except:
            raise Http404("hmmm can't seem to find product")
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

in cart.html I changed

> {% if cart.product.exists %}

to

> {% if cart.products.exists %}